# How to exclude admin urls from lowercase rule in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento

I need to exclude admin urls (index.php/admin/) in a lowercase rule

Example url for excluding:
http://local.copy.com/index.php/admin/sales_shipment/index/key/c20735e30dccd35392a225501f0e35c81adfcf8ebb5b640fe52592500c00a9f3/

For lowercase urls I use the next rule

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/admin(.*) [OR]
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301]
```

Note: I didn't tried it for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/admin(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion